# How to decompress zlib files created with ByteArray.compress?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, zlib

I work on a Flex application that creates compressed files and uploads them on a server. The files are created with ByteArray.compress method, which is zlib compression. I can decompress them using Python API on the server but I prefer to keep the files compressed there. I want to be able to download and decompress the files later, however WinZip and WinRar fail to decompress them. When I google for zlib utility, I only find zlib dll library. I need a simple application for Windows (and/or Linux) that is capable of decompressing zlib files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, zlib compression will certainly compress the data down, but it doesn't include the file headers that make it a "ZIP" file that can be opened using apps like Windows, WinZip or WinRar.

Adobe has [some documents that explain how to READ a zip file](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ByteArrays_3.html), including information about the header.  If you want to WRITE a zip file, just use this information to write out the header with the data.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I used FZip library (https://github.com/claus/fzip) to produce a valid zip file.